# Showing $\frac{1}{z}$ cannot be approximated by any polynomial on $\partial{\mathbb{D}}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

I am trying to understand why $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ cannot be approximated by any polynomials uniformly on $\partial\mathbb{D}$.

I  have the following idea, but I am really not sure if it is valid.

Given $\epsilon>0$, I assume that there exists a sequence of polynomial $P_n(z)$ such that 
$$\|P_n-f\|_{\partial\mathbb{D}}\leq \epsilon.$$

I think to get a contradiction, I should prove $(P_n)$ is convergent to $f$ uniformly in $\mathbb{D}$, which is a contradiction, since the uniformly convergent limit of analytic functions must be analytic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: polynomials satisfy the Cauchy Integral Theorem.

Comment: At first I thought, I got what you meant, but now I doubted. Here is what I think: $p_n(z)\to \frac{1}{z}$ uniformly on $\partial\mathbb{D}$. $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{C(0,1)}\frac{1}{z(z-a)}dz=0$, where $a\in D(0,1)$

Comment: Never mind I got it, I think using the Cauchy Integral equation we can show that this sequence of polynomials converges uniformly to $\frac{1}{z}$ in $\mathbb{D}$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: What I meant was $\int_{C} p_n(z)\; dz = 0$ but $\int_{C} f(z)\; dz \ne 0$.